# C++/CLI convert existing application do managed code

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I've got an existing application written in Borland C++ Builder. My client wants it rewritten in C#/WPF. This requires a lot of work and is a complex task because I need to rewrite the whole (huge) algorithm. I was thinking of a way to reuse the code and to be able to create only GUI in C#/WPF. Is this possible? Would that be easy? How can I make C++ classes visible to .NET ?

If you could give me brief answers with some links/examples I would be grateful.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, no it isn't easy, learn C++/CLI.  Brief enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your old C++ code in a C++/CLI wrapper and build it into a DLL file. It should then be visible in any .NET project.

Depending on your algorithm/function structure, this may change a little, but the basic form, and the way I did this, is the following. Keep in mind this is a VERY basic example, but I tried to include the key points:

**1. Define the CLI wrapper**

```
using namespace System;

#include "myAlgorithmClass"

public ref class MyCLIWrapperClass //the 'ref' keyword specifies that this is a managed class
{
public:

    MyCLIWrapperClass(); //Constructor

    //function definitions are the same, though some types,
    //like string, change a little. Here's an example:
    String ^ GetAString(); //the "String" is the .NET "System.String" and the ^ is sort of a pointer for managed classes

    //int, double, long, char, etc do not need to be specified as managed.
    //.NET code will know how to handle these types.

    //Here you want to define some functions in the wrapper that will call
    //the functions from your un-managed class. Here are some examples:
    //Say that your functions in the Algorithm class are int Func1, double Func2, and std::string Func3:
    int Func1();
    double Func2();
    String ^ Func3();

private:
    //All private functions and members here
    myAlgorithmClass algor;
};
```

**2. Implement the wrapper class**

```
using namespace System;
#include <string> //For the string function ex. below
#include "myAlgorithmClass"

MyCLIWrapperClass::MyCLIWrapperClass()
{
    algor = myAlgorithmClass(); //create instance of your un-managed class
}

int MyCLIWrapperClass::Func1()
{
    return algor.Func1(); //Call the un-managed class function.
}

double MyCLIWrapperClass::Func2()
{
    return algor.Func2(); //Call the un-managed class function.
}

String ^ MyCLIWrapperClass::Func3()
{
    //Converting a std::string to a System.String requires some conversion
    //but I'm sure you can find that somewhere on Google or here on SO

    String ^ myString = "";
    std::string myUnmanagedString = algor.Func3(); //Call the un-managed class function.

    //Convert myUnmanagedString from std::string to System.String here

    return myString;
}
```

After you write the wrapper class and compile it into a class library you can create a reference to the .DLL file in a C# project and C# should see the managed wrapper class and all its public functions.

Another thing to note is that if you are creating new managed objects in C++ you use the keyword "gcnew" instead of "new". So a new string would be `String ^ someString = gcnew String();`

Finally, here are some links to some things about CLI that may help:

[CLI - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)
[CLI - Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/cppcliintro01.aspx)
[CLI - FunctionX](http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Well, As far as i can remember by head, you can use interops for that matter. 
It is in fact better to continue using a code that was for a long time tested, and is stable. With net Interop Services you can create a very good bridge between the new app and the old one.

examples:
http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread136041.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_managed/interop/article.php/c6867